# How do I get rid of a featureless window?

Tags: windows-xp, window

I have a two-monitor system (laptop with external screen) running XP. At (seemingly) random intervals, a window will pop up on my laptop screen. It is full-sized, but not maximized (I can move it around, but it covers the entire screen, including the task-bar). It is the exact color of my background (which is a solid color), and the title-bar has no text or buttons. It doesn't have a tab in the task-bar.

When it pops up, I can't destroy it, so I just push it off the screen, and ignore it until the next time that it pops up.

I don't know  what process creates it, so I can't kill it from  the task manager. Any help?

Comment: Your computer seems to be compromised. You should decide if you consider acceptable working on a compromised computer. In my case, I would inmediately stop doing anything until having a clean PC.

Answer (score 8):

To do this, you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).

When you start it, make sure to enable *Show Details for All Processes*:

[image: Show Details for All Processes]

Then you're going to want to drag & drop the crosshair icon onto your window in question.
[image: Crosshair icon]

Now the process that owns the window will be selected in the process list in Process Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Does it show in task manager applications tab?

If it does, right click on it in task manager and select "go to process"

Comment: Not that I can tell.

Comment: The asker says he doesn't know what process creates the window, so he doesn't know which one to kill. How is this answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Alt+F4 often works on windows that otherwise can't be closed or interacted with.  (It's the standard Windows shortcut for close application.)

This also works for windows that appear in the Alt-Tab list, but aren't visible when you Alt-Tab to them.  I.e. When going through the Alt-Tab list the thumbnail and title appear, but when you try to Alt-Tab to that window nothing appears on screen.